# Bootstrap Modal not opening, but backdrop appearing`

Tags: jquery, twitter-bootstrap

I am using a Bootstrap Modal to display a message. I have a link triggering the modal:

```
<a class="row-btn" id="where-we-are" href="#" onclick="$('.www').modal('show');"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-map-marker"></span><br>Where We Are</a>
```

The page goes dark from the backdrop, but the modal does not show.

```
<div class="modal fade www">
  <div class="modal-dialog">
    <div class="modal-content">
      <div class="modal-header">
        <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close"><span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span></button>
        <h4 class="modal-title">Sorry, that's classified.</h4>
      </div>
      <div class="modal-body">
        <p>Our location is top secret. We have many enemies who track us day and night to discover our secrets. Who knows, you might be one of them!</p>
      </div>
      <div class="modal-footer">
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
      </div>
    </div><!-- /.modal-content -->
  </div><!-- /.modal-dialog -->
</div><!-- /.modal -->
```

Is the problem because I am triggering the modal from a link? Why is the backdrop appearing, but not the modal itself?

Comment: Try `onclick="$('.www').modal('show'); return false;"`, not sure if this will solve the problem

Comment: No, still not showing. Page: http://tricksfortheweb.net46.net/

Comment: The code you provided works as it's supposed to so it must be something else that's causing the issue. Could potentially be where you placed the actual modal on the page; another element could be blocking it.

Comment: Found the problem, it was a bit of code from when I used a jQuery UI dialog. Now it's working.

Comment: Yes I was just looking at your site and noticed that you got it to display correctly. There is a <div class="modal-backdrop fade in"></div> that is being added to the bottom of your code when you click on your modal link. That div class has is the one showing that background color when you click your link

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have a posted a working code of yours

In **Bootstrap** we do have option to provide the target div.classname as `data-target="provide class Name"` and `data-toggle="modal"` to mention that its a modal

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.5/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.5/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>


<a class="row-btn" id="where-we-are" href="#" data-toggle="modal" data-target=".www" ><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-map-marker"></span><br>Where We Are</a>

<div class="modal fade www">
  <div class="modal-dialog">
    <div class="modal-content">
      <div class="modal-header">
        <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close"><span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span></button>
        <h4 class="modal-title">Sorry, that's classified.</h4>
      </div>
      <div class="modal-body">
        <p>Our location is top secret. We have many enemies who track us day and night to discover our secrets. Who knows, you might be one of them!</p>
      </div>
      <div class="modal-footer">
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
      </div>
    </div><!-- /.modal-content -->
  </div><!-- /.modal-dialog -->
</div><!-- /.modal -->
```